# NameError: free variable 'player_one_rps' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I'm quite new to coding, and I've been trying to make a text-based game with a menu. The game itself works fine, but once I try to incorporate a menu, i get the error "NameError: free variable 'player_one_rps' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope".
I have been googling it like a mad for some time now, but the few answers I find uses too advanced code for me to understand it yet.

(I tried changing the scopes and indents, I tried calling different functions at different indents, I tried assigning an argument to the functions, also, to have the main menu as the last function in the code – the list goes on..)

Here is the code for the menu and game option 1:

def main():
    print("\t\t*** Welcome to this totally adequate game! ***")

```
def game_menu():
    """Displays game menu and prompts user for input"""
    menu_choice = input("""What do you want to do?

                        1 - One player: rock, paper, scissor, lizard, spock
                        2 - Two player: rock, paper, scissor, lizard, spock
                        3 - Surprise! Bonus feature
                        4 - User guide
                        5 - Quit

                        Enter the menu number to access: """)
    while True:
        if menu_choice == "1":
            print("One player: rock, paper, scissor, lizard, spock")
            player_one_rps()
            break
        elif menu_choice == "2":
            print("Two player: rock, paper, scissor, lizard, spock")
            player_two_rps()
            break
        elif menu_choice == "3":
            print("Surprise! Bonus feature")
            dad_jokes()
            break
        elif menu_choice == "4":
            print("User guide")
            user_info()
        elif menu_choice == "5":
            print("Quit game")
            exit()
        elif menu_choice != 1 - 5:
            print("Error, choose a valid number")

    # print(menu_choice)

game_menu()
main()

# First game
def player_one_rps():
    """One player rock, paper, scissor, lizard, spock - game"""
    import random

    def instructions():
        """Displays menu and simple instructions on how to play"""
        print("Welcome to rock, paper, scissor, lizard, spock!")
        play = input("\nNavigate by \"yes\", \"no\", and numbers.\nNew game?:").lower()
        if play == "yes":
            print("1. Rock")
            print("2. Paper")
            print("3. Scissors")
            print("4. Lizard")
            print("5. Spock")

        elif play != "no":
            print("an error has occured. Please type \"yes\" or \"no\":")
            instructions()

    def get_user_choice():
        """Prompts the player to pick a 'weapon'"""
        choice = int(input("What do you choose?: "))
        if choice > 5:
            print("Invalid number, please try again....")
            get_user_choice()
        elif choice < 1:
            print("Invalid number, please try again....")
            get_user_choice()
        elif choice == 1:
            print("You chose rock")
        elif choice == 2:
            print("You chose paper")
        elif choice == 3:
            print("You chose scissor")
        elif choice == 4:
            print("You chose lizard")
        elif choice == 5:
            print("You chose spock")
        return choice

    def get_pc_choice():
        """The computer chooses a random weapon"""
        choice = random.randint(1, 5)
        if choice == 1:
            print("PC chose rock")
        elif choice == 2:
            print("PC chose paper")
        elif choice == 3:
            print("PC chose scissor")
        elif choice == 4:
            print("PC chose lizard")
        elif choice == 5:
            print("PC chose spock")
        return choice

    def winner(user_choice, pc_choice, user_wins, pc_wins, ties):
        """Calculates if the player or computer won the match"""
        if user_choice == 1 and pc_choice == 3 or pc_choice == 4:
            print("\nYou win.")
            user_wins = user_wins.append(1)
        elif user_choice == 2 and pc_choice == 1 or pc_choice == 5:
            print("\nYou win.")
            user_wins = user_wins.append(1)
        elif user_choice == 3 and pc_choice == 2 or pc_choice == 4:
            print("\nYou win.")
            user_wins = user_wins.append(1)
        elif user_choice == 4 and pc_choice == 2 or pc_choice == 5:
            print("\nYou win.")
            user_wins = user_wins.append(1)
        elif user_choice == 5 and pc_choice == 1 or pc_choice == 3:
            print("\nYou win.")
            user_wins = user_wins.append(1)
        elif user_choice == pc_choice:
            print("\nTie")
            ties = ties.append(1)
        else:
            print("\nPC won")
            pc_wins = pc_wins.append(1)
        return

    def game_total(user_wins, pc_wins, ties):
        """Displays the total score"""
        user_wins = sum(user_wins)
        pc_wins = sum(pc_wins)
        ties = sum(ties)
        print("Your final score: ", user_wins)
        print("PC\'s final Score: ", pc_wins)
        print("Total ties: ", ties)

    def main_one_p():
        """Main instructions for how the game runs"""
        user_choice = 0
        user_wins = []
        pc_choice = 0
        pc_wins = []
        ties = []
        final_user_wins = 0
        final_pc_wins = 0
        final_ties = 0
        Continue = "yes"
        instructions()
        while Continue == "yes":
            user_choice = get_user_choice()
            pc_choice = get_pc_choice()
            winner(user_choice, pc_choice, user_wins, pc_wins, ties)
            Continue = input("Would you like to play again: ").lower()
            if Continue == "no":
                print("This is the final scores.")
                break
        game_total(user_wins, pc_wins, ties)

    main_one_p()
player_one_rps()
game_menu()  # Returns player to the main menu
```

(sorry if it is quite long)

Could anyone help point me in the direction of my mistake? Explanations and tips on how to fix it would also be greatly appreciated :)

In general, I'm thankful for all feedback, as i really want to become better at coding.

Comment: Main point: You call `game_menu` which calls `player_one_rps` before `def player_one_rps` is defined later in the code. Overall the whole program should be refactored. Function definitions inside of function definitions? Yes, there may be reasons to do that, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The global function must have a higher declarative code than where it is called. Simply reposition the function. The function `game_menu` must be below the function `play_one_rps`. The other functions are the same.